# How to save a given range in excel as csv?

Tags: vba, excel

I have data in excel columns and I want to extract first 7 columns and save it in another csv file. The file name would be in a particular format basis the information I collect from user using a form and other details such as time-stamp.

I am using the following code:

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "" '<~~ The start folder path for the file picker.
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

NextCode:

    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=MyPath & MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.CheckCompatibility = False
       .Close False
    End With
```

But this writes all the columns in the output CSV and also closes the open xls (which I don't want to close).

Comment: Tip: instead of `If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode`, you could do `If .Show = -1 Then Exit Sub` and avoid `GoTo` and the line label.

Answer (score 0):

That's a rather playful approach. Maybe not too practical, I also suspect this to be rather slow with large amounts of data.

However: if you make use of recordsets in other parts of your routine, this might be worth looking into.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportRange()

    Dim mytxt As String
    Dim fld As Object

    With GetRecordset(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).UsedRange)

        For Each fld In .Fields
            mytxt = mytxt & fld.Name & ";"
        Next fld

        mytxt = mytxt & vbNewLine

        While Not .EOF
            For Each fld In .Fields
                mytxt = mytxt & fld.Value & ";"
            Next fld
            mytxt = mytxt & vbNewLine
            .movenext
        Wend

        Debug.Print mytxt

    End With

    Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.csv" For Binary Access Write As #1
        Put #1, , mytxt
    Close #1

End Sub
```

It utilizes this function for reading ranges (`.UsedRange` in my example) into recordsets, without having to define ADODB-references and setting up a DB-Connection:

```
Function GetRecordset(rng As Range) As Object
    'https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/vba-trick-of-the-week-range-to-recordset-without-making-connection/

    Dim xlXML As Object
    Dim rst As Object

    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set xlXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    xlXML.LoadXML rng.Value(xlRangeValueMSPersistXML)

    rst.Open xlXML
    Set GetRecordset = rst
End Function
```

Edit:

`Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\test.csv" For Binary Access Write As #1` creates the file (if it doesnt exist) and opens it.

Obviously, you can use something like
`MyPath & "\test' & format(now, "yyyymmdd_hhmmss") & ".csv"`
instead to use a File with timestamp in the folder you picked with the FolderPicker

Comment: How do I name the file using the information I collect from user in a form and time stamp and save the csv in a folder of choice?